# UVa-401:Palindromes, Output limit exceeded

Tags: c

I am trying the problem 401 - Palindromes UVa online Judge, but I have always been getting a fail... You can find the problem [here](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=342)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char reverse_t[36] = {' ','1','S','E',' ','Z',' ',' ','8',' ',
                     'A',' ',' ',' ','3',' ',' ',
                     'H','I','L',' ','J','M', ' ',
                     'O', ' ', ' ', ' ','2','T',
                     'U','V','W','X','Y','5'};

int is_mirror(char a,char b){
    if(a>='1' && a<='9'){
        if(reverse_t[a-'0'] == b) return 1;}
    else if(a>='A' && a<='Z')
        {if(reverse_t[a-'A'+10] == b) return 1;}
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char line[21];
    size_t len;
    int is_palinedromes, is_mirrored;
    while(scanf("%20s",line)){
        is_palinedromes = 1;
        is_mirrored = 1;
        int i;
        len = strlen(line);
        for(i = 0;i<len/2;i++){
            if(line[i] != line[len-1-i])
                is_palinedromes =0;
            if(!is_mirror(line[i],line[len-1-i]))
                is_mirrored = 0;
        }
        if((len%2==1)&&(is_mirrored))
            if(!is_mirror(line[len/2],line[len/2]))
                is_mirrored = 0;
        if(is_palinedromes && is_mirrored)
            printf("%s -- is a mirrored palindrome.\n",line);
        else if(is_mirrored &&(!is_palinedromes))
            printf("%s -- is a mirrored string.\n",line);
        else if((!is_mirrored)&&is_palinedromes)
            printf("%s -- is a regular palindrome.\n",line);
        else
            printf("%s -- is not a palindrome.\n",line);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I store the mirror of letters in the array **reverse_t** and I can check the mirror of a letter by the function **is_mirror**.

and the verdict is "**Output limit exceeded**"

I will appreciate any suggestions. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that there is no end for inputting, so I just change the code

```
while(scanf("%20s",line))
```

to

```
while(scanf("%20s",line)!=EOF)
```

and then I got a AC :).